# Ground texture comes up blurry using the UV Rect Tool

Tags: unity, 2d, textures, image

Im trying to recreate the ground as this sample sprite sheet: https://opengameart.org/content/post-apocalyptic-expansion

I downloaded the sprite sheet and extracted the top left block and saved it separately and added it as a default object not Sprite/UI. I then added a UI > Raw Image to my scene, added the imported texture. But as I expand it, it becomes blurry, even the UV rect does not seem to help. I though the UV rect was supposed to repeat the texture.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the 'Tiling' inside the material section of the inspector (im assuming you are using Unity from the how you've asked this question). The tiling part is just under wherre you set the colour etc and it defaults as 1 , but you can make it 10 for example in the X and Y and that will be 10x the detail